# Is it possible to get a red-eyes photo on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone

Photos taken on old phones gave us red eyes caused by flash.
Nowadays they are automatically removed without any manual action.

For some reason I need these "original" red eyes somehow.

My question is - does modern ios api allow getting photos with people having red eyes? or it is completely hidden in the camera chip?
If it's possible than what is this api?

I've spent lot of time trying to understand whether it is possible or not. If you can help getting me an existing app from the appstore (as an evidence that it's possible)

Comment: Isn't that actually fixed by flash technology rather than camera chip? I remember that cameras used to have a "preflash". Nowadays your mobile doesn't really flash, it uses a light therefore the retina has time to accomodate.

Comment: [Read more about it here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-eye_effect#Photography_techniques_for_prevention_and_removal)

Comment: @Sulthan, Exactly but if it's a preflash only - is it possible to take a photo without it? I even tried to record a video with flash always on in a dark room - the eye still appeared as black wich can't be done without some aftereffect. On first versions of iOS/iphone you had to remove the red-eyes effect manually at least sometimes. Funny thing that I need this red-eye back=)

Comment: Leshka, I need same. Were you ever able to disable (programmatically) the preflash?

Answer (score -1):

Most modern phones and camera will have a feature to correct this when the photo is taken. In most cases this is on by default or something you can enable.

Comment: That's exactly what I asked for. But I didn't find a way to disable this feature. I have both android and iOS devices - and I can't get any info whether taking a photo with a red-eyes effect on a modern and popular ios/android device is possible.